# Calling a onCreate method inside onCreate method in android

Tags: java, android, gps

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if ( !locationManager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
            showDialog();

        }

    }

    public void showDialog(){
        //GPS-Dialog
        GpsEnablingDialog gpsAlert;
        try {
            gpsAlert = new GpsEnablingDialog();
            gpsAlert.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "GpsAlert_Tag");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("My-Log-Msg",e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

**I tried with**::

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if ( !locationManager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
            showDialog();
            try {
                onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("My-Log-Msg",e.toString());
            }
        }

    }

    public void showDialog(){
        //GPS-Dialog
        GpsEnablingDialog gpsAlert;
        try {
            gpsAlert = new GpsEnablingDialog();
            gpsAlert.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "GpsAlert_Tag");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("My-Log-Msg",e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

---

**Log**::

```
04-23 14:22:19.969: D/My-Log-Msg(1586): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached
04-23 14:22:20.419: D/gralloc_goldfish(1586): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

**What i understand**::

- From the log i can clearly understand that i am trying to attach
  something that's already attached
- Why i am doing this:: First time the activity is loaded, it checks
  for the GPS is enabled or not and a dialog pops up and takes me to
  Settings page
- Now i enable the GPS, and press back button on the phone i return to
  `MainActivity`
- i want to restart the activity lifecycles from begining and check
  these GPS and proceed further

***Any ides on how to achieve this***

Comment: Are you tried to restart your activity in onResume() method??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never explicitly call `onCreate()`. Android calls it when an Activity is created. You should check out [the activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and see if you can't move some code to another callback method (such as `onResume()`) when the user returns from the settings activity.

If you really wish to have `onCreate()` called again, you should check out [`Activity.recreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate%28%29) which was added in API level 11. If you're below that API you can work around this with the following code:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

This finished the activity, and starts it again with the same intent that it was created with in the first place.